# mapreduce program to calculate max avg electricity consume. i have attached the csv file

Tags: python, max, average

```
//here is my csv file
year,jan,feb ,march,april,may,june,july,august,september,october,november,december,Average
```

1979,23,23,2,43,24,25,26,26,26,26,25,26,25
1980,26,27,28,28,28,30,31,31,31,30,30,30,29
1981,31,32,32,32,33,34,35,36,36,34,34,34,34
1984,39,38,39,39,39,41,42,43,40,39,38,38,40
1985,38,39,39,39,39,41,41,41,0,40,39,39,45

```
//i want max average =45 and min averge=25
```

mapper code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import sys  
for line in sys.stdin:  
    line = line.strip()  
    tokens = line.split(',')  
    try:  
        year = tokens[0]  
    average = tokens[13]  
    print '%s\t%s' % (year, average)  
except ValueError: 
    pass
```

here is my reducer code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import sys  
import math  

# Get input from stdin
for line in sys.stdin:
    #Remove spaces from beginning and end of the line
    line = line.strip()
    # parse the input from mapper.py
    year, average = line.split('\t')
    # calculate year of maximum useage, year of minimum useage
    try:
        year = int(year)
        max_avg= max(average)
        print '%s\t%s'% (year, max_avg)
```

Comment: Your last try lacks an except. What is your problem? Please find a better suited title and explain your problem by [edit]ing your post. Please share some data inside your question - not in the title. Read about https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting